# Undefined Index Name when trying to pass values from Jquery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, undefined-index

So, I'm working on figuring out how to post data from Jquery to PHP, And as much as I follow the examples I've found on the threads here, I keep getting an "Undefined Index Name" error.

My code thus far for the JQuery side is

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#div2").text('Hey');
    $("#div1").load('testFile.txt');
    setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'script.php' });
    $("#div1").load('testFile.txt');}
    ,100);



  });
  function sub(){

     var msg = $("#name").val();

     $.post('chat.php',{'name':"1234"},function(){
$("#div2").load('chat.php');
});  
 };

</script>
```

The html forms and buttons I'm using

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2">Um</div>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>
</form>
<button id="submission" onclick="javascript:sub();">Errrr</button>
```

And the PHP side I'm going to

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
 $myFile = "testFile.txt";
 $fh = fopen ($myFile, 'a+') or die("Cannot Open File");
 fwrite ($fh, $_POST['name']);
 fclose($fh);

?>
```

I'm about at a loss from where to do. All files are within the same folder and filenames are correct as far as I can find.

Comment: Why would you run a post and then load the same script seperately..?

Comment: That's me chasing my tail trying to trace why I keep getting that error.

Comment: what is this supposed to do? `$.ajax({ url: 'script.php' });`..nothing sent and no handler for anything returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is most likely that you're doing this:

```
$.post('chat.php',{'name':"1234"},function(){
    $("#div2").load('chat.php');
});
```

You're effectively sending the data `{'name': '1234'}` to the file and then just loading the file?
You'll get the error because you `load()` the file without sending it params.

Looking at the [**`jQuery.post`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) manual, you'd see that you can get a response with something like this:

```
$.post('chat.php',{'name':"1234"},function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

While you use something like `echo` or `print` to effectively "return" content to the ajax call.

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Now check in your console and see if there is a response.

Comment: I'm getting the value returned in the console, but am getting no signs that the PHP script is properly running.

Comment: If you're getting the value you send with `{'name': name}` then the script should be running correctly...

Comment: @Draketh how is this going for you..?

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to solve it, and feel a bit stupid for it, I had two conflicting scripts running, which was my main problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Draketh Did this answer your question at all?